# Projection of portion of equirectangular image

Tags: spheres, image-processing, projection

I am working on a project and a doubt arises when thinking on image projections.

I have and equirectangular image created using a cubemap like the following:

[Equirectangular projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uPnN.jpg)

If I draw a black square like the one that can be seen stroked on the image above and perform a crop keeping the part of image within the square, what classical projection corresponds to the cropped image?

Note that the square is centered on the image and strategically drawn to crop the image to a certain horizontal field of view I am interested in. I do not want the whole 360 degrees.

I did some tests overlapping images with Gimp and think it is equidistant but I am not really sure.

Thanks,